# PHP SSL Certificate Serial Number in hexadecimal

Tags: php, security, ssl, x509, serial-number

I need to display SSL certificat information about Serial Number.
When I use

```
$cert = file_get_contents('mycert.crt');
$data=openssl_x509_parse($cert,true);
$data['serialNumber']
```

I receive like
    -5573199485241205751
But when I run command
    openssl x509 -in 'mycert.crt' -noout -serial
I receive
    serial=B2A80498A3CEDC09
is it possible receive in PHP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Petey B the idea was interesting so have help me to find direction to search.
The solution is:

```
$serial_number= strtoupper(dechex($serial_number));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably recieving the serial number as a byte array. Convert those bytes to hex and you should get the serial that you are seeing using openssl.

Answer (score 1):

```
php > $value = hexdec('B2A80498A3CEDC09');
php > echo dechex($value);
b2a80498a3cee000
```

That doesn't seem to work. Probably due to float conversion.

I saw one solution with bcmath.

Here's from confusa (http://www.assembla.com/code/confusa/git/nodes/lib/ca/Certificate.php?rev=a80a040c97fde2c170bb290d756c6729883fe80a):

```
                    /*
                     * PHP will return the serial as an integer, whereas
                     * everybody else use the hex-represenatation of the
                     * number.
                     *
                     * Due to the fact that Comodo uses *insanely* large
                     * serial-numbers, we need to be a bit creative when we
                     * get the serial as PHP won't cope with numbers larger
                     * than MAX_INT (2**32 on 32 bits arch)
                     */
                    $serial = $this->x509_parsed['serialNumber'] . "";
                    $base = bcpow("2", "32");
                    $counter = 100;
                    $res = "";
                    $val = $serial;

                    while($counter > 0 && $val > 0) {
                            $counter = $counter - 1;
                            $tmpres = dechex(bcmod($val, $base)) . "";
                            /* adjust for 0's */
                            for ($i = 8-strlen($tmpres); $i > 0; $i = $i-1) {
                                    $tmpres = "0$tmpres";
                            }
                            $res = $tmpres .$res;
                            $val = bcdiv($val, $base);
                    }
                    if ($counter <= 0) {
                            return false;
                    }
                    return strtoupper($res);
```

I don't have bcmath enabled so I cant test it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/math/intro.html) for this purposes:

```
<?php
include('Math/BigInteger.php');

$cert_body = file_get_contents('mycert.crt');
$cert_decoded = openssl_x509_parse($cert_body, true);
echo $cert_decoded['serialNumber'] // outputs 5573199485241205751

$cert_serial = new Math_BigInteger($cert_decoded['serialNumber']);
$cert_serial = strtoupper($cert_serial->toHex());

echo $cert_serial // outputs B2A80498A3CEDC09
?>
```